# How to keep column but not include in groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id   type1         type2    val
a    main       regular      3
a    main       unregular    5
a    main       large        3
b    second     regular      80
b    second     unregular    90
```

I want to do groupby by columns id type1 and max() by val. but when I do that:

```
df.groupby(["id","type1"])["val"].max().reset_index()
```

I get:

```
id   type1        val

a    main          5
b   second        90
```

But I want:

```
id   type1         type2    val

a    main       unregular    5
b    second     unregular    90
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `idxmax` function to find the index where the maximum `val` occurs and then map the value of `type2` -

```py
out = df.groupby(["id","type1"])["val"].agg(["max", "idxmax"])
out.loc[:, 'type2'] = out['idxmax'].map(df['type2'])
```

**Output**

```
           max  idxmax      type2
id type1                         
a  main      5       1  unregular
b  second   90       4  unregular
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated the answer. How about this

```
df.groupby(['id', 'type1']).aggregate({'val':'max'}).merge(df, on=['id', 'type1', 'val'], how='inner')
```

result looks like this

```
  id   type1  val      type2
0  a    main    5  unregular
1  b  second   90  unregular
```